# Grabbing the email of account used to access a Google sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to have the email address of the user accessing a Google sheet in cell A1. (Any user who accesses given sheet should see his email in cell A1) Is there a direct function in Google Sheets or it has to be done with GAS?

Answer (score 0):

I guess, this isn't possible since Google Sheets can't display individual data per user.